# How to fix that error “Fatal Error in ContentView.swift”?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, fatal-error

I’ve problem with fatalError(). I try to adding to a list of words but in this line there is problem it says:

> fatal Error in ContentView.swift

and i don’t why this happened my code was totally correct.
The code of this error:

```
// id were are * here* then there was a problem - trigger a cradh and report the error
    fatalError("could not load start.txt from bundle.")
```

And the whole code is;

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var usedWords = [String]()
    @State private var rootWord = ""
    @State private var newWord = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    TextField("enter your word", text: $newWord)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                }
                Section {
                    ForEach(usedWords, id: \.self) { word in
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "\(word.count).circle")
                            Text(word)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(rootWord)
            .onSubmit(addNewWord)
            .onAppear(perform: startGame)
        }
    }
    
    func addNewWord() {
        // lowercase and trim the word, to make sure we don:t add duplicate words with case differences
        let answer = newWord.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        // exit if the remaining string is empty
        guard answer.count > 0 else { return }
        
        // extra validation to come
        withAnimation {
            usedWords.insert(answer, at: 0)
        }
        newWord = ""
    }
    
    func startGame() {
        // 1.find the URL for start.txt in our app bundle
        if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start",withExtension: "txt") {
            // 2.load start.txt into a string
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                // 3.split the string up into an array of strings, splitting on line breaks
                let allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                // 4.pcik one random word, or use "yamori" as a sensible default
                rootWord = allWords.randomElement() ?? "yamori"
                
                // if we are here everything has worked, so. we can exit
                return
            }
                
        }
        // id were are * here* then there was a problem - trigger a cradh and report the error
        fatalError("could not load start.txt from   bundle.")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any idea? How to fix that error

Thanks.

Comment: Either the url for "start.txt" is nil or `try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL)` fails.

Comment: It would be better to remove the `try?` statement in favour of `try` and wrap this in a `do/catch` block and print the error. Then you would know why it fails.

Comment: If we use do/catch, can you show me how it should look by coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this failing is either the url for "start.txt" is nil or `try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL)` fails. In order to help you debug and become an understanding why your current code design is bad consider this design:

```
func startGame() {
    // 1.find the URL for start.txt in our app bundle
    guard let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start",withExtension: "txt") else{
        //assign the default value
        rootWord = "yamori"
        // if the url is not found this will print in the console
        print("File could not be found")
        return
    }
    
    do{
        // 2.load start.txt into a string
        let startWords = try String(contentsOf: startWordsURL)
        // 3.split the string up into an array of strings, splitting on line breaks
        let allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        // 4.pick one random word, or use "yamori" as a sensible default
        rootWord = allWords.randomElement() ?? "yamori"
    } catch{
        //if the file couldn´t be read this will print the error in the console
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works thank you, but why did it give an error, I followed the 100 day with swiftUI tutorial and wrote the same codes, why didn't it work for me, but it worked completely for those who followed the other 100 day with swiftUI course, I am using swift playground, is it related to it?

Comment: @user19460962 Who knows. I don´t know the implementation of this on your device. Glad i could help. If this answer helped you solve the problem please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It’s work for now, but i’ve another problem with my previous project can u help me? About it

Comment: Post it and me or anybody else will give it a try.